# How to include an XML schema (.xsd) in a JSON schema?

Tags: xsd, jsonschema, api-design, raml

I want to define a JSON API response using JSON Schema.

Embedded in part of the API response is a complete, well-formed, schema valid XML string. The XSD of this XML string is a given.

Two part question:

1. How do I include the XSD in the JSON Schema such that the JSON Schema will also require the XML string to be schema valid in order for the whole API response to be valid?
2. **If this is not possible, does anyone have another suggestion how to include the XSD at least in the specification?** I'm working in RAML 0.8.

Comment: You cannot. The only thing you can do is validate the JSON and then at a later point extract the XML and validate it separately.

Comment: Thanks @TomRedfern. Do you have a suggestion for the RAML 0.8 spec?

Comment: I'm sorry I've only used Swagger, not RAML. Swagger is based on JsonSchema

Comment: Hmmm. Is it easy to convert to Swagger if I have "something" already?

Comment: Yes it's easy, but even if you do this, you'll still not be able to achieve your "number 1" above (validating XML).

Comment: Thanks @TomRedfern that's not a problem. Just wanted to specify it as a "requirement" not actually implement it in some executable way.

Comment: Are you using JavaScript?

Comment: Is using xml (xsd) directly not an option ?

Comment: @Michael - you can do this by using the "description" functionality in swagger. This allows you to create a description (which supports markdown) and attach it to any element in the definition. I've included the gist of our conversation in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I include the XSD in the JSON Schema such that the JSON Schema
>   will also require the XML string to be schema valid in order for the
>   whole API response to be valid?

You cannot. The only thing you can do is validate the JSON and then at a later point extract the XML and validate it separately.

> If this is not possible, does anyone have another suggestion how to
>   include the XSD at least in the specification? I'm working in RAML
>   0.8.

I've only used Swagger, not RAML. Swagger is also based on JsonSchema.

The only thing you can do here is to include a detailed specification that the contained XML should be compliant against such-and-such an XSD. You can do this by using the "description" functionality in swagger (or equivalent if it exists in RAML). This allows you to create a description (which supports markdown) and attach it to any element in the definition